# cc: language CC not recognized

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

When I'm migrating my app from Solaris C compiler sunstudio/v12/SUNWspro to Linux C compiler GCC version 4.1.2 20080704, I'm seeing a CC not recognized error.

C Command: The same command is working in solaris but not working in Linux with Gcc 4.1.2.

```
CFLAGS          = -c -g -xCC -I. -I${ORACLE_INCLUDE}
```

Error:

```
cc: language CC not recognized
cc: language CC not recognized
cc: check*****maint.c: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

Do we need to change any parameters to be compatible with GCC 4.1.2 ?

Comment: What's `-xCC` ? Just remove it.

Comment: If you're migrating to 64-bit linux, you may also need to specify `-m32` which IIRC is what Oracle's compiler defaults to (if you were using the default)

Comment: GCC4.1 is **obsolete** and unmaintained so don't use it. Current GCC is [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/), in november 2017 (a lot of progress made since GCC4.1). GCC 8 will be released in a few weeks. Read about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)

Comment: ...and if you see any errors tagged with `-fpermissive` you'll want to add that as well.  Shouldn't be an issue with C, but with C++ it might be.

Answer (score 4):

[The `-x` option selects the input language](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-x), so `-xCC` attempts to use `CC`, which is not known to `gcc`.  With Solaris `cc`, `-xCC` enables C++-style comments, so you may have to use `-std=gnu99` instead of `-xCC` (but it is also possible that your build of GCC 4.1 supports such comments by default).